# How to parse strange duration format like "P0DT22H10M0S" in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to parse duration format like "P0DT22H10M0S". Is there a gem or built-in method in Ruby?

And what name of this format?

Comment: That's ISO 8601. Use that as a search term.

Comment: (*Responding to now-deleted comment about it not being a date.*) No, it's a duration. ISO 8601 [covers those too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Comment: Yes. I found solution. Thanks. I can use `ActiveSupport::Duration.parse('P0DT22H10M0S')`

Comment: Consider adding an answer, it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSupport::Duration.parse('P0DT22H10M0S')